# how can i fix my express backend redirect to backend port instead of redirect to frontend port

Tags: express, axios

on my front end(vue on port 9999),the axios request is:

```
this.$axios.post('/login', {
        username: this.username,
        password: this.password
      }).then((response) => {
        if (response) {
          if (response.data.code === 200) {
            this.$store.commit('login',response.data.result);
            this.$router.push({path: '/'})
```

and in my backend(express on port 7890) route is:

```
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/loginSuccess',
        failureRedirect: '/loginError',
        failureFlash: true
    })
);

app.get('/loginSuccess', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.baseUrl);
    res.send(responseToJson(200, req.user, 'login successed!'));
});

app.get('/loginError', function (req, res) {
    res.send(responseToJson(500, null, 'ユーザーまたはパスワードが正しくありません.....'));
});
```

but when i login,it's show:

```
GET http://localhost:9999/loginSuccess 404 (Not Found)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js?b50d:187
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js?b50d:13
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js?5270:53
request @ Axios.js?0a06:108
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js?0a06:140
wrap @ bind.js?1d2b:9
login @ Login.vue?7463:46
invokeWithErrorHandling @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1863
invoker @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:2188
original._wrapper @ vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:6961
Login.vue?7463:63 Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at createError (createError.js?2d83:16:1)
    at settle (settle.js?467f:17:1)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onloadend (xhr.js?b50d:54:1)
```

my proxy config is :

```
devServer: {
      port:9999,
      proxy: {
        '/api': {
          target: 'http://localhost:7890/',
          changeOrigin: true,
          pathRewrite: {
            '^/api': '/'
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

it's backend request is redirect to frontend's port.
how can i change backend's redirect to backend port?

Comment: When the front-end makes the request, you need to process the response from the server at the front end that completes the cycle of request and response.

Comment: @bharath I do have process the response but this res should come from route localhost:7890/loginsuccess . But now when i request localhost:7890/login it's success but it redirect to localhost:9999/loginsuccess which is not exist so this shown 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below option as mentioned in the [passportjs link](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport#authenticate-requests)

```js
app.post('/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/loginError',
        failureFlash: true
    }, (req, res) => {
        res.status(200).send({user: req.user});
    })
);
```